# AngularJS app within a wordpress blog

Tags: angularjs, wordpress

I have just started with a blog using Wordpress.com and I'd like to add a small Angularjs clientside-only app in a page on the blog. What's the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? You just have to call Angular (lib, ng-app, ng-controller) and start the business. I did that before, you should consider using Wordpress API plugin, to provide you all your Wordpress content as a REST API (it's way easier).

Comment: The problem is not with building the angular app. How do I embed the app in a wordpress page? I am new to wordpress, not angular.

Comment: Just as you would do in whatever HTML website ?

Comment: Create a new page on your blog, write your HTML codes, in wordpress.com you can't change codes and upload your theme i think. So you have to create a page on your blog if you want to use your html tags.